# How to prevent Apache hangs when PHP APC cache completely fills up?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, apc

When APC cache is full, it hangs Apache. Apache responds to requests, however waits forever for APC cache to free some resources, but this will never happen.

I run every 10 minutes CRON job with my own small expunge script, which deletes expired entries from APC. Ok, I could add more memory to APC and/or I could run the expunge script more often. But that's not real solution, I am looking for some new way how to deal with issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really the final solution, but I have written small [PHP APC expunge script](http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/php-apc-expunge-script) that I had proposed in my question. This script is run by CRON every 10 minutes and it manually removes expired items. It's far not perfect solution, but at least it helps a lot.

I am though still looking for final solution.

Answer (score 1):

I find that setting a ttl changes APC's behavior when cache is full. By default, if the ttl is 0, APC has to empty the cache when it gets full. From the manual:

> In the event of a cache running out of
>   available memory,the cache will be
>   completely expunged if ttl is equal to
>   0. Otherwise, if the ttl is greater than 0, APC will attempt to remove
>   expired entries.

Comment: Well, but this doesn't quite happen. When APC cache is completely full it just hangs and so does Apache. It accepts new connections but they don't get completed.
There is plenty of items that are expired, but APC doesn't expunge them (which logically should). And it doesn't matter if ttl is 0 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a line to a script that is executed often to check wether the cache is nearly full and if it is, deal with it.
An example of such script could be a script that establishes the connection to a database.

Comment: Well, executing such script in every script call will slow response time of each script a bit. And most of the time it is never needed, because use of cache is at minimum level. So I would just go with cron job executed more often, say 5 minutes. 
But I would still prefer some more elegant method, like Apache recognising something is wrong and restarting itself.... But I have not found anything about this possible feature ....